# Formatting external drive in CentOS previously used on OS X

Tags: filesystems, usb, usb-drive

I have a USB key they I want to use on a CentOS box. The USB key was previously used on OS X so I want to erase it to make it writable by CentOS.

Can someone help me with the commands I need to run?

I'm guessing it has something to do with fdisk and mkfs (possibly mkfs.ext3). If it makes any difference, the USB key is 32GB.

The disk is located at `/dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what level of compatibility you want you can either go for ext3 or the more universal FAT32. To format as FAT32:

```
$su
$fdisk /dev/sdb
$mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

Or if you want to format for ext3:

```
$su
$fdisk /dev/sdb
$mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

As an aside if you want to rename the USB pendrive; to rename FAT32:

```
$sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::usb-key
```

Or for ext3:

```
$sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 usb-key
```

For a general look at formatting, check out [this howto](http://www.ehow.com/how_1000631_hard-drive-linux.html).

Comment: Thanks, the howto plus this link helped me find what I needed: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-mount-a-usb-flash-drive-380376/

Answer (score 0):

Most USB keys use the [FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) format (more precisely [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32)), which is a simple format native to older versions of Windows and almost universally supported.

If you formatted the key using HFS(+) or UFS, and you now want to format it as ext3, first find out if there is a partition on the key. Run `ls /dev/sdb*`. If this shows only `/dev/sdb`, there is no partition, so create the filesystem directly onto `/dev/sdb`. If this shows one partition (probably `/dev/sdb1` but it could be a different number), create the filesystem there. If there are several partitions, you can put different filesystems on them, or repartition the disk.

Run `file - </dev/sdb1` to check what filesystem is currently on that partition (maybe use a different number or no number as determined above). If you're sure you want to make a new filesystem, run `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1`. For removable media, you probably don't want any reserved block, so run

```
mkfs.ext3 -m 0 /dev/sdb1
```

If your Linux is recent enough, you may want [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) or [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), as they are supposed to be better for flash devices (though I don't know if this applies to low-end flash media as found on USB keys).

But again, there's rarely a reason not to use FAT on a USB key.